# Get all font styles with matplotlib.font_manage in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts

please, 
is it possible to print out every style that each of the listed typefaces has? So I know that for example Arial has Bold, Regular, Italic and whatever else. Thanks! Or would you recommend some other tool for doing this? I am on Windows 7.

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
#help(matplotlib.font_manager)
fonts = [f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist]
print(len(fonts))
for i in fonts:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The `get_style()` and `get_variant()` methods let you explore some of the font space.

You may want to iterate over several possibilities, calling `score_style()` to determine if a style is available. Or just iterate and look at the result of `findfont()`, letting *it* work out which styles are locally available. If you post your iterating code along with its results, we may be able to offer additional font hints.